# Capture product url data in case of pagination using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I have fetched the html data from a site and trying to fetch product urls:

```
def get_soup(url):
soup = None
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
return soup

def get_category_urls(url):
    soup = get_soup(url)
    cat_urls = []
    categories = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'menu_oc'})
    if categories is not None:
        for c in categories.findAll('a'):
        if c['href'] is not None:
            cat_urls.append(c['href'])
        return cat_urls

def get_product_urls(url):
     soup = get_soup(url)
     prod_urls = []
     if soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pagination'}):
         for link in soup.select('div.links a'):
             if link.string.isdecimal():  # dump next and last links
                prod_urls.append(link['href'])
     print("Found following product urls::", prod_urls)
     return prod_urls

if __name__ == '__main__':
category_urls = get_category_urls(URL)
product_urls = get_product_urls(URL)
```

How to efficiently identify the pagination condition in above loc?

screen shots of actual site with pagination:

[image: with pagination]

and without pagination:

[image: without pagination]

- [site link](http://www.infantree.net/shop)
- [pagination category](http://www.infantree.net/shop/index.php?route=product/category&path=63_64)

Comment: what's the point in hiding the real site? the sample you linked doesn't even have a pagination. and if you google the `<meta>` content, you obviously get where you didn't want us to.

Comment: I have edited my question, please see the link and share your solution.

Comment: this is not a page with a pagination like the one of your screenshot

Comment: check the link-pagination category

Comment: my answer works fine then

Comment: not at all, it gives me blank urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be okay

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_soup(url):
    soup = None
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        html = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return soup


def get_category_urls(url):
    soup = get_soup(url)
    cat_urls = []
    categories = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'menu_oc'})
    if categories is not None:
        for c in categories.findAll('a'):
            if c['href'] is not None:
                cat_urls.append(c['href'])
        return cat_urls


def get_all_products(url):

    prod_urls = []

    soup = get_soup(url)
    prod_urls.append(get_product_urls(soup))

    links = get_pagination(soup)
    print("Found those pages:", links)
    if not links:
        return prod_urls

    for link in links:
        soup = get_soup(link)
        prod_urls.append(get_product_urls(soup))

    print("Found following product urls:", prod_urls)
    return prod_urls


def get_product_urls(soup):
    links = soup.select('div.product-list .span .name a')
    return [link['href'] for link in links]


def get_pagination(soup):
    pages = soup.select('div.pagination div.links a')
    return [link['href'] for link in pages if link.string.isdecimal()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    URL = 'http://www.example.com/shop/index.php?route=product/category&path=63_64'
    category_urls = get_category_urls(URL)
    product_urls = get_all_products(URL)
```

Comment: I have edited my question and given the link, please see once and share me your solution.

Comment: it's not blank as you said. and it's exactly the pagination link you asked. you just can't change the question and goals as they go. if you have another question ask a new one. but i consider your first question here answered: "I am not able to find out efficient way to identify the pagination condition in above loc."

Comment: modified the answer to reflect its real purpose

Comment: can you modified my code to get the product url in a seperate function which is asked in the question not the category url?

Comment: guess it's ok now

Comment: One issue in this code is that your code does not work if I use the original url; it works only if use the category url.